# How to generate .pi file that can be recognize by WingIDE

Tags: autocomplete, pyqt, wing-ide

Because I want to use pyqt in WingIDE, but there is a serious problem, that My WingIDE cannot recognize pyqt's functions
Can you tell me how to generate .pi file using WingIDE, or can you tell me how to transform .sip file into WingIDE.

Comment: Knowing the exact version of Wing and PyQt would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wing should be doing this automatically for PyQt4 if you have it using the right Python.  You can check this by trying to use PyQt4 in Wing's Python Shell or looking at sys.executable there.  If that is incorrect, change Python Executable in Project Properties.

If you want to try to generate PIs manually from an extension module you can use src/wingutils/generate_pi.py in your Wing installation.  A typical command line would be
   python generate_pi.py myextension myextension.pi

The .pi file can then be put alongside the .so / .pyd or in the pi-files 
sub-directory of your settings directory.

There are a few more options that generate_pi.py supports; a list of 
these is printed to stdout when generate_pi.py is run without any arguments.

In the case of PyQt you probably need to use the --magic-code command line option.  If you look at Wing's Source Analysis > Advanced > Scripting Helper Snippets preference you can see the magic code that is used by Wing when it tries to do this automatically for you.